# ruby eventmachine timer interval too big error

Tags: ruby, timer, eventmachine

I use the Timer class of ruby eventmachine library as follow:

```
EM::Timer.new(interval) do
    # do something
end
```

If I set the interval value too big (bigger than the max Integer value) such as '5183877.350508', it will raise an error:

> integer 5183883250 too big to convert to `int'

Is this a limit of Timer interval of eventmachine or a bug?
What should I do if I have to set the timer interval bigger (such as several months or years).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do depends on your use case.

While I think relying on your process to continue running uninterrupted for several months on end is optimistic, it could conceivably happen. However unless this is a watchdog timer (eg. your server should definitely die after 4 months for some reason) I think you most likely want a scheduler instead.

I believe [Rufus Scheduler](http://rufus.rubyforge.org/rufus-scheduler/) integrates reasonably well with EventMachine.